# Access data from lightning component to visual force page

Tags: lightning-aura-components

In my client side controller of my lightning component, I tried the below expecting to be able to access "window.d" in the visual force page.
But in the VF page, window.d is "undefined"

```
var w= window.open('https://c.cs95.visual.force.com/apex/EBIStaffMap', " ","scrollbars=no,resizable=1,width=800,height=500");
w.d="hello"
```

But, when I execute the above from the console window, the VF page renders and in the console of the VF page, I can see the value of window.d as "hello". But, in the debugger of the VF page, window.d is "undefined"

Has anyone experienced the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightning's SecureWindow implementation won't let you do this. Instead, use something like the following:

```
w.postMessage('d', 'https://c.cs95.visual.force.com');
```

You'll need to arrange for the two windows to communicate with each other to coordinate the data transfer.

The Visualforce page should send a signal when it is ready to receive a message:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(data) {
  window.d = data; // Remember to check origin before blindly accepting data
});
if(window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {
  window.opener.postMessage('readyToReceiveData', 'https://my-lightning-domain.lightning.force.com');
}
```

Then, the Lightning controller should have also set up a message listener:

```
({
    init: function(component, event, helper) {
      window.addEventListener('message', function(data) {
        var win = component.get("v.win");
        if(win && !win.closed) {
          win.postMessage('some-data-here', 'https://c.cs95.visual.force.com');
        }
      });
    },
    openOtherWin: function(component, event, helper) {
      var win = window.open('https://c.cs95.visual.force.com','','...');
      component.set("v.win", win);
    }
})
```

I realize this is all kind of complicated, but it has to be this way in order to be secure.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful. I shall try this. Will window.addEventListner work with IE11?

Comment: @Neema yes, it works on all browsers that Lighting supports.

Comment: thankyou. I noticed in the openOtherWindow function, attribute v.win is being set. In the init function, var v.win = component.get(“v.otherWindow”) should be component.get(“v.win”), right?

Comment: @Neema oops. Yeah. That was a mistake on my part.

Comment: I am having trouble seeing the data in my VF page.   My function in client side controller renderMap: function(component, event, helper) {
      var hostname = component.get('v.hostname');
        console.log('In renderMap ' + hostname);
      if(component.find('staffMap').get('v.checked')){
        var win = window.open(hostname+'apex/EBIStaffMap'," ","scrollbars=no,resizable=1,width=800,height=500");
        component.set("v.mapWin", win)
        if(win && !win.closed) {
          win.postMessage('neema', 'https://c.cs95.visual.force.com');
        }
      }
    }

Comment: My visual force page. <apex:page controller="mapController">
    <script>
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeElementHeight);
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  if(event.origin === 'https://test.salesforce.com'){
    *** console.log('Data received ' + event.data); //In the console window , I see  ‘Data received {"cmd":"sfdcsession::ready","msgtype":"SfdcSession"}’
  }
});

</apex:page> I am expecting to see 'neema' in the console window, but I see {"cmd":"sfdcsession::ready","msgtype":"SfdcSession"}.

Comment: Also, in my org we are not lightning ready, I created a lightning component that is surfaced in a visual force page,. so based on your example code, I am not sure what I need to use for the url in the post message if(window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {
  window.opener.postMessage('readyToReceiveData', ***'https://my-lightning-domain.lightning.force.com');
}  I just skipped this part and used window.postMessage directly after opening the apex page in my client side controller.

Comment: I was able to set up the two way communication, I can see the message from the child vf page in the console. But, from the window.addListener in the init function, I get the win attribute that was set, print it in the console window, I see "win is SecureIFrameContentWindow: [object Window]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }". Then I use win.postMessage('Hello','https://c.cs95.visual.force.com'); the vf page(EBIStaffMap) does not receive the message. Why could reason be? The {"cmd":"sfdcsession::ready","msgtype":"SfdcSession"}’ } }) that I saw was when the vf page is opened using window.open

Comment: This was very helpful to me. I have not been successful in receiving messages in the visual force yet, I am marking this as the best answer. It be helpful for others trying to do the same